# How can you print out more than one decimal place within the same line in C++?

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and I was wondering how can you print out two different decimal places within the same line. For instance, the first value should have one decimal place and the second value should have three decimal places. I know how to use setprecision to have different decimal places for different lines, but not how to have it on the same line.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would use setprecision for different lines? Can't you just do the same thing but without printing a newline between subsequent calls to setprecision?

Comment: You don't have to put `endl` just because you're done with a line of *code* ...

Comment: If you know how to use "setprecision" ... then why don't you *TRY* it?  Write a single "cout" with multiple doubles ... and multiple "setprecision" ... and see what happens :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double precision_value = 12.409583385;
    
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << precision_value << " " << setprecision(4) << precision_value;

    return 0;
}
```

A few things to note:

In the same print statement, the `fixed` only needs to be set once and works for the remainder of the stream. The `setprecision()` can be updated to any value you need after that.

Also, prefer to remove `using namespace std;` and utilize the namespace `std::` wherever required. But, for demonstration purposes, this suffices for your example needs.